# azure search lookup document count as query

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

If i look up document to bring data from azure search - does it affect the queries per second per index indicate in [here](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/pricing/details/search/)

I want to know if i can use the azure search to host some data and access it without affecting the search performance.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes a lookup is considered a query.  Please note that we do not throttle your queries and this number listed in the page you point to is only meant as a very rough indication of what a single search unit with an "average" index and an "average" set of queries could handle.  In some cases (for example, if you were just doing lookups which are very simple queries), you might very likely get more than 15 QPS with a very good latency rate.  In some cases (for example, if you have queries with a huge number of facets), you might get less.  Please note, that although we do not throttle you, it is also possible that you could exceed the resources of the units allocated to you and will start to receive throttling http responses.

In general, the best thing to do is track the latency of your queries.  If you start seeing the latency go higher then what you find acceptable, that is typically a good time to consider adding another replica.

Ultimately, the only way to know for sure is to test your specific index with the types of queries and load you expect.

I hope that helps.

Liam